# Can't create local calendar on iOS

Tags: ios, eventkit

I am attempting to create a local calendar on iOS. I request access to `EKEntityTypeEvent` and have it granted, create the calendar from the `EKEventStore` (yes, the same instance I requested access from), find the `EKSourceTypeLocal` then set it on my new calendar. Calling `saveCalendar:commit:error` (with `commit:YES`) returns `YES` and there is no `NSError`. The resulting calendar has a `calendarIdentifier` assigned.

But then when I flip to the iOS Calendar app, my calendar is not there! I've tried on the iOS 7 and 8 simulators (after a "Reset content and settings...", so there's no iCloud configured) and on an iCloud-connected iPhone 5s with iOS 8. Nothing works!

What have I missed?

I have created a bare project with the following view controller to illustrate the problem:

```
@import EventKit;
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger calendarCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EKEventStore *eventStore;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.resultLabel.text = @"";        
    self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)userDidTapCreateCalendar:(id)sender {
    EKAuthorizationStatus status = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];

    if (status == EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                            if (granted) {
                                                [weakSelf createCalendar];
                                            } else {
                                                weakSelf.resultLabel.text = @"If you don't grant me access, I've got no hope!";
                                            }
                                        }];
    } else if (status == EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        [self createCalendar];
    } else {
        self.resultLabel.text = @"Access denied previously, go fix it in Settings.";
    }
}

- (void)createCalendar
{
    EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityMaskEvent eventStore:self.eventStore];
    calendar.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Calendar %0lu", (unsigned long)++self.calendarCount];

    [self.eventStore.sources enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(EKSource *source, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) {
            calendar.source = source;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [self.eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
    if (success && error == nil) {
        self.resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Created \"Calendar %0lu\" with id %@",
                                 (unsigned long)self.calendarCount, calendar.calendarIdentifier];
    } else {
        self.resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", error];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code on a device, and it works OK (change `EKEntityMaskEvent` -> `EKEntityTypeEvent`). I can see new calendar in iOS calendars. 
Looks like simulator does not actually saves your calendars. I've got the same issue some time ago.

Comment: Of course that was it. It beggars belief that this even compiles. _But dynamic languages are so awesome!_